# Consider the following set in the dictionary order.?

Tags: general-topology

> Consider the following set in the dictionary order. Which are linear continua?
>
> (1) $\mathbb{Z_+}\times [0,1)$
>
> (2) $[0,1)\times \mathbb{Z_+}$

my answer :$1) $is true since, for $x\neq y$, ($n\times x,m\times y$) always contains the points $n\times (\dfrac{x+y}{2})$ and $m\times (\dfrac{x+y}{2})$.

for answer  $2)$:is true since, for $x\neq y$, ($x\times n,y\times m$) always contains the points $(\dfrac{x+y}{2})\times n $ and $(\dfrac{x+y}{2})\times m$

Is my answer is correct  ?

pliz verify its

Answer (score 1):

No, in the second one, there are no points between $(a,n)$ and $(a,n+1)$ for any $a\in[0,1)$ and $n\in \mathbb Z_+.$

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen....as   if i take  a=0 and  n = 1   now  (0,1) and (0,2)     has   contain  a point  i mean  we can find a point between (0,1) and (0,2)

Comment: as  im not getting  what  u want  to say ??

Comment: @lomber Sorry, not understanding. I am claiming that, for instance, there is no point between $(0,1)$ and $(0,2).$

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen.......here there  is  a  point  1/2  which  is  lie  in both (0,1)  and (0,2),,,???  which point  you   are talking about?

Comment: @lomber By $(0,1)$ and $(0,2)$ I mean the ordered pairs in $[0,1)\times \mathbb Z_+,$ not the open intervals. I am saying there is no point in between these two in the dictionary order on $[0,1)\times \mathbb Z_+.$

Comment: can u  elaborate  how  can  i expressed the  order  pairs  in $[0,1) \times Z_+$? as  im   was  looking munkre book,,,,i didn't understands  its

Comment: @lomber $[0,1)\times \mathbb Z_+$ is the set of ordered pairs, the first of which is an element of $[0,1)$ and the second of which is a positive integer. So the ordered pair $(0,1)$ is an element, and $(1/\sqrt{2},354)$ is, etc. The dictionary order will have first element $(0,1)$ and then $(0,2), (0,3)$ and so on. But $(0.00001,1)$ will be greater than all of these and have $(0.00001,2)$ as a successor. The fact that every  element has an immediate successor makes this not a continuum. On the other hand, $\mathbb Z_+\times [0,1)$ is order-isomorphic to the usual ordering on $[0,\infty).$